# How to fetch multiple google fonts

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, google-fonts

I'm working on a personal project in NextJS which uses around 5 Google fonts.

The fonts are being fetched only if the page `New` is reloaded or if I navigate to the page using `<a></a>` tag instead of `<Link></Link>`.

This is my current code for the page that requires the fonts,

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const fonts = getFontNames(); // returns a static list of strings like ['Monserrat', 'Product Sans', ...].
    const fontsLink = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=" + fonts.map(cV => cV.replace(/ /g, '+')).join('&family=') + "&display=swap"
    return {
        props: {
            fonts,
            fontsLink
        }
    }
}


export default function New({ fonts, fontsLink }) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>New</title>
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
                <link href={fontsLink} rel="stylesheet" />
            </Head>
            ...
       </div>
}
```

This is how I navigate to the page `New` ,

```js
<Link href="/new">
   <a className={styles.card}>
      <h2>New &rarr;</h2>
   </a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've disabled browser cache in the network tab before testing fonts.

```js
import PageLayout from "../components/Page/PageLayout"
import Head from "next/head"

export default function About({ fonts, fontsLink }) {
  return (
      <Head>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
        <link href={fontsLink} rel="stylesheet" />
      </Head>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const fonts = ["Monserrat", "Product Sans", "Girassol"]
  const fontsLink =
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=" +
    fonts.map((cV) => cV.replace(/ /g, "+")).join("&family=") +
    "&display=swap"
  return {
    props: {
      fonts,
      fontsLink,
    },
  }
}
```

Using either means of navigation loads the fonts for me.

```
<Link href="/About">About</Link>
<Link href="/About">
    <a>
       <h2>About page using Link</h2>
    </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Yes, technically what I'm doing must work. It works in development, but not in production. Is this due to NextJS's static generation? Or the fact that I'm using a service worker for installable PWA?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I settled for a CSS import. It's a bit late, but it works.